# Metro App, high memory usage caused by background image

Tags: xaml, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have three nested grids where first two of them has background images with sizes 291 KB and 185 KB. When i run the app i see that my app is using about 130 MB of RAM. I debugged the app to see what causes such a huge memory consumption and realized that when i remove background images it decreases to about 25 mb.

Am i doing something wrong? You can find the markup below.

```
<Grid Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootStyle}">
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/Images/bubbleless_background.png" />
    </Grid.Background>        
        <Grid>
            <Grid.Background>                    
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/Images/bubble_background_new.png" Stretch="None" AlignmentX="Left" AlignmentY="Top"/>
            </Grid.Background>
        </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: How large in pixels are the background images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The size of the image on disk is NOT a measurement for the size in memory.

In memory the size is `its width * its height in pixels * 4 bytes per pixel`

You are adding two images; depending on their sizes (in pixels!) this can take a lot of memory.